# Functional notation and functions on sets of equivalence classes

Tags: functions, soft-question, predicate-logic, equivalence-relations

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are sets and that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. Further assume that one wants to define a function $f:X/\sim \to Y$. In order for $f$ to be a function, the usual difficulty is to show that it is well defined. This means that for any $(x,y), (x,z) \in f$ we need to have $y=z$. **My question is**, is it allowed to use the notation $f(x)$ prior to showing this?

More precisely, when trying to prove that $f$ is well defined, we might say let $x=[a]$ and $x=[b]$ be two representations with $a,b \in X$. Then we need to show that $f([a])=f([b])$. Here we are using the functional notation before knowing that it actually is a function. I am not sure if this is "usual" or even done at all, [since usually functional notation is only used when the defined object is unique.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_predicate) However, since the linked article is concerned with formal logic and not "everyday mathematics" im not sure if its still fine to use it prior to actually showing well definedness.

[In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185159/proving-that-a-function-is-well-defined) the agreed upon opinion seems to be that it is not allowed to do that. However, I think this is done in an analogous way when talking about essentially unique objects anyways. So for example, when defining the tensor product $A \otimes B$ we only get that this is essentially unique but still use a functional symbol to denote this. Another example can be found in $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, where one often writes $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta_{\epsilon} (...)$. Strictly speaking, $\delta_{\epsilon}$ is also a function symbol but obviously the existence of it is not unique, so when using this notation, we dont infer $\delta_{\epsilon}=\delta_{\epsilon'}$ when $\epsilon=\epsilon'$. So as far as I can tell, one usually doesn't care too much about notation here, as long as one is sufficiently careful with the inferences. Thus, as long as I don't infer that $f(a)=f(b)$ whenever $a=b$, using the notation prior to proving $f$ is well defined should do no harm, should it?